# Ubuntu PPC64 14.04 LTS with dual VIO on IBM Power8

Tags: system-installation, powerpc, ppc64le

Does Ubuntu PPC64 14.04 LTS support the dual disk I/O path provided by dual VIO servers on IBM power8 systems?

Alternatively, is it wise to install this server with storage provided by just a single VIO server?

Answer (score 4):

The multipath packages are included in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for ppc64el as well, which handle the dual VIOS scenario (as well as Fibre Channel, and IPR controllers w/ multipath capability)

See [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com), 14.04 LTS (Server column), DM-Multipath, sections  "Setting up DM-Multipath Overview" then "DM-Multipath Setup Overview", and "Device Mapper Multipathing" then "Installing with Multipath Support".

Basically, either:

1. Install Ubuntu with the `disk-detect/multipath/enable=true` option in the kernel command line; or
2. In an already installed system, install the `multipath-tools-boot` package (this installs the `multipath-tools` package automatically).

Note: On option 2, some users had boot problems [(LP bug)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/multipath-tools/+bug/1432062) if not using `user_friendly_names` (which is enabled by default on option 1).

You can enable it before installing `multipath-tools-boot` with this command:

```
$ cat <<EOF | sudo tee -a /etc/multipath.conf
defaults {
    user_friendly_names yes
}
EOF
```

If you enabled it after installing `multipath-tools-boot`, just update the `initramfs`; for example:

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mauricio. Multi-path package installed and functioning.

Answer (score 0):

I would add that you should look at running three VIOS.  This would allow you to upgrade or service a VIOS without exposure.  I would never run on one VIOS as they sometimes do go down from hardware and software issues.  This just based on my experience with PowerVM in very large configurations.